# jquery traversing across different type of element

Tags: jquery

```
<div></div>
<a></a>
<a class='here'>
```

I want find here from div

`but $(this).next().next().find('.here')` did not seem working

Comment: Your code was not working because .find()looks within the target element and $(this) <the div itself>.next()<the emtpy anchor>.next()<.here> already refers to .here so it is trying to find .here, in itself.

Answer (score 0):

if `this` is the `div` then

```
$(this).next().next('.here')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.next('div.here');`

```
$(this).next().next('a.here');
```